# Finding a subgroup of Multiplicative group $\mathbb Z_{32}$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I am backing on some basic points about the multiplicative groups, like $\mathbb Z_{32}$ ,to review and I am really in a bad confusion to write the elements of a subgroup of it. For example, I want to write $<\bar{5}>$. So is it as finding all integers as $m$ such that $5k\equiv m,~~\text{mod} 32, k\in\mathbb Z$? Thanks!

Comment: $\mathbb Z_{40}$ is not a group under multiplication. It is a group under addition.

Comment: @IttayWeiss: Can I edit the question, now?

Comment: did you try editing your question?

Comment: Yes, you can. $\,$

Comment: @Berci: I mean $(\mathbb{Z}/32\mathbb{Z})^{\times }$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the group operation is addition, then, in general,
$$\langle 10\rangle=\{0,10,20,30,40,50,...,-10,-20,-30,-40,-50,...\}\,.$$
Now it is $\langle 10\rangle=\{0,10,20,30\}$. If $a$ is coprime to $n$, then it generates the whole $\Bbb Z_n$, i.e. $\langle a\rangle=\Bbb Z_n$, because **Bezout's identity** implies that $ka\equiv 1\pmod{n}$ for some $k\in\Bbb Z$, that is, $1\in\langle a\rangle$, and then, as everybody is of the form $1+1+1+1+$.. in $\Bbb Z_{40}$.

If the group operation was multiplication instead, then, in general
$$\langle 10\rangle=\{1,10,100,1000,...,1/10,1/100,1/1000,...\}\,.$$
Note however, that $10$ is not an element of $\Bbb Z_{40}^\times$, as it contains only the coprimes to $40$.

**Update:** Before the edit there was a modulo $40$ exercise..
So, as $32=2^5$, exactly the odd numbers are coprime to it, so $\Bbb Z_{32}^\times=\{\bar 1,\bar 3,\bar 5,...\bar 29,\bar 31\}$. Then, for $\langle 5\rangle$ modulo $32$, calculate its powers modulo 32:
$$\begin{align}
&\quad\quad1,& 5,& 25\equiv -7,& -35\equiv -3,& -15, \\
(5^5\equiv\,)&  -75\equiv -11,& -55\equiv 9,& 45\equiv 13,& \dots
\end{align}$$
By Fermat's theorem, we should get $5^{16}\equiv 1\pmod{32}$ as $\varphi(32)=16$.

Comment: Now, I see that.

Comment: So $<\bar{3}>=\{3^k,k\in\mathbb Z\}$?

Comment: Yes. But, this is periodic mod $m$ (if $\gcd(m,3)=1$), e.g. $3^4=81\equiv 1\pmod{40}$, so $\bar 1/\bar 3=\bar{27}$ in $\Bbb Z_{40}$, and $\bar 1/\bar 9=\bar 9$.